# Tkinter - Why is my background/frame not re-painting?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am not sure if I am on the right track here-- but I started GUI programming with Python.

I have all of my buttons and entries worked out. The main problem I am having is with the method that rolls my die and places the result.

```
def roll(self):
    self.die = Die(int(self.sides.get())) # gets from label
    t = self.die.roll()
    t += int(self.mod.get()) # gets from label
    self.result = Label(self.root, text=t).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
```

Is my problem the fact that I am re-instantiating a Label over the old one? Shouldn't the old Label's text be destroyed and the frame should only show the new label in its place?

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you're not using objects at their best values. You should modify you code in this way:

- each time you need a new roll, you instantiate a new `Die`. Why not keeping the same instance?
- each time you want to display the roll, you instantiate a new `Label`. Maybe you're not aware of this, but you can update the label text (and any Tkinter widget), using its `configure()` method. This would mean that you need to `grid` the instance only the first time.

By the way, `.grid` returns `None`. If you want to keep reference of the result label, you have to use two lines for `Label` instantiation:

```
self.result = Label(self.root, text=t)  # first creating instance...
self.result.grid(row=2, colum=1, sticky=W)  # ... and placing it in self.root
```

Try to update your code like this. You will certainly feel the need to move some of this code to the `__init__()` function of `self`, so write it in your question as well.